# LINQ2SQL - Cross join emitted when I want inner join

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008

This emits inner joins, which is what I want and works:

```
var q =
    from itm in esdc.items
    join itmImg in esdc.itemImages on itm.itemId equals itmImg.itemId
    join itmIdent in esdc.itemIdentities on itm.imgIdentityId equals itmIdent.itemIdentityId
    join startImgs in esdc.vStartPgImgs on itmImg.imgId equals startImgs.imgId
    select ...
```

This works too, but cross joins were emitted.  How do I get inner joins?  I double checked the entities and the relationships are correct.

```
var q =
    from itmIdent in esdc.itemIdentities
    from itm in itmIdent.items
    from itmImg in itm.itemImages
    join startImgs in esdc.vStartPgImgs 
        on itmImg.imgId equals startImgs.imgId
    select ...
```

If you need me to post the emitted SQL and the entity setup, let me know.

Comment: Why do you care? Any sane RDBMS will do the same thing on explicit inner join and on a cross join with a filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put it simply: you get inner joins if you use the first form. Multiple `from` clauses represent cross joins (sort of, anyway <sup>1</sup>) in LINQ.

Basically, if you want inner joins, use multiple `join` clauses.

---

<sup>1</sup> (I say sort of because the subsequent sequences can depend on the earlier ones... but for LINQ to SQL they're almost always cross joins.)